# Importing CSS Module in a Shadow DOM's Style Tag (`@import url()`) Using Stimulus Controller

Tags: css, shadow-dom, ruby-on-rails-7, esbuild

I want to import a CSS module (in this case `@algolia/autocomplete-theme-classic`) in the style tag within the shadow root. The stimulus controller looks like this:

```js
// import '@algolia/autocomplete-theme-classic'

export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    const shadowRoot = this.element.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })

    const style = document.createElement('style');
    const autocompleteCss = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@algolia/autocomplete-theme-classic@1.11.0/dist/theme.min.css';
    style.textContent = `@import url(${autocompleteCss});`;
    shadowRoot.appendChild(style);
  }
}
```

I want to give a CSS file in node_modules (`@algolia/autocomplete-theme-classic/dist/theme.css`) as an argument to `@import url()` instead of from jsdelivr. I use esbuild as a JS compiler. What do you think I should do?

I tried:

```js
import css from '@algolia/autocomplete-theme-classic'

export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    const shadowRoot = this.element.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })

    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.textContent = css;
    shadowRoot.appendChild(style);
  }
}
```

But what is rendered as:

```
<style>
@import url([object Object])
</style>
```